# Set request access email address through CSOM

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, office-365, csom

In the server side object model it's possible to set the request access email address through the property `SPWeb.RequestAccessEmail` ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.requestaccessemail.aspx)).

Since we are moving our SharePoint tenant to Office365 I'm looking for a way to set this value. I know it's possible to do so manually in the UI (Site Settings > Site Permissions > Access Request Settings) but since we have some self-service site creation, it's not possible to change it manually each time a web has been created.

Unfortunately there is no property `Web.RequestAccessEmail` in the client side object model.

Is there a way to set this email address through the property bag (aka `Web.AllProperties["__SecretKey"]`), a web service (`_vti_bin`, etc.) or any other workaround?

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: You could use an event receiver:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408183(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I was also searching for an option to do this but it seems to be impossible or did you already found a way to do it?

Comment: @Marlou Unfortunately not. But you could vote on my feature request: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/6234918-set-the-access-requests-email-address-and-properti

Comment: I definitely did!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the newest release of the "SharePoint Online Management Shell" (v16.0.4630.1200) the included `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` adds the property `RequestAccessEmail` to the `Web` class.

Download: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588

You may use this DLL until the NuGet-Package is released.

EDIT: Since version `16.1.4727.1200` of the `Microsoft.SharePointOnline.CSOM` NuGet-Package the `RequestAccessEmail` property is supported.

Comment: Could you specify the cmdlet to use? I do not see anything in Set-SPOSite...

Comment: @grisha Try `Set-SPOWeb -RequestAccessEmail "mail@domain.com`"

Comment: Thank you, Stefan, but still no :( I tried reinstalling Powershell on 2 different machines and the cmdlet is still not available. I posted it as a separate question here http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/163693/set-spoweb-requestaccessemail   Please kindly help if you have any suggestions

Comment: @grisha It was just a guess. I have no experience with the PowerShell commands. I just use the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll` out of this package and use it from my C# code.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this property is not accessible via `CSOM`.

How to retrieve all available properties for Web client object:

```
var allProperties = clientContext.Web.AllProperties;
clientContext.Load(allProperties);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is possible but in my opinion a hack.
I wrote an article to discuss if this is a valid way to do it - [Manipulating SharePoint UI over an IFrame to add missing clientside Features](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136377/manipulating-sharepoint-ui-over-an-iframe-to-add-missing-clientside-features)

Here's the Code:

```
//quite dirty hack but at this point the only possibility to set the AccessRequest mail via clientside
function setAccessRequest(mail) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    //set the setrqacc.aspx link
    var setrqaccUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_layouts/15/setrqacc.aspx?type=web';
    //create setrqacc.aspx hidden iframe
    iframe.setAttribute('src', setrqaccUrl);
    iframe.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
    iframe.onload = function () {
        //this will fire 2 times - the first time when its initially loaded. the second after the changes were applied (page is reloaded (postback) after the submitbutton is triggered)
        var $iframeInput = $('input[id*="_txtEmail"]', $(iframe).contents());
        if ($iframeInput.length) {
            //initial load - apply settings
            $iframeInput.val(mail);
            //gets iframeInput's parent so the current input can be placed inside
            var $iframeBtn = $('input[id*="_btnSubmit"]', $(iframe).contents());
            //trigger the post
            $iframeBtn.trigger('click');
        } else {
            //second load - do callback
            callback('AccessRequest');
        }
    };
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}
```

It should be wrapped in a waitingdialog and some warnings when the user tries to exit the page. Loading a page in an IFrame can take some time and this code is doing it twice.