# Save Calculated Column Formula in Language Localized notation using REST or JSOM?

Tags: 2013, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula, localization

*[multiple blogs/posts out there noted the issue, no solution was ever published]*

#### What is required to save a *Localized* Calculated Column Formula using JSOM/REST?

I am injecting the script below into a FldEdit.aspx page.

- It **saves** the Formula you are editting **on every keypress**
- providing **immediate** feedback on errors

This al works fine on English sites but on non-english sites the Formula is displayed in a Localized format

### But I can NOT save the Localized format, using REST or JSOM code, the Formula is not accepted.

This screenshots shows the Dutch Localized UI,
**not** making any changes to the Formula, my custom save action is rejected (red error)

[image]

If I change the Formula (in that Localized Dutch site!) to English notation I can save the Formula using JSOM or REST.

[image]

#### It IS stored. a reload of the FldEdit.aspx page displays it in dutch again.

A click on the standard OK button saves the **Localized** Formula without any issues.
If I change the Formula to English Locale and use the SharePoint OK Button to save/close the page I (ofcourse) get an error.

### ?? What is required to save a *Localized* Calculated Column Formula using JSOM/REST?

.

#### Scriptfile

execute in an existing Formula (FldEdit.aspx page)
as [Chrome snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470711/chrome-developer-tools-what-is-snippets-support) or as [a Bookmarklet](http://mrcoles.com/bookmarklet/) or as a GreaseMonkey/TamperMonkey script or stick it into your MasterPage.

```
/*global SP,document,STSHtmlDecode,clearTimeout,setTimeout,_spPageContextInfo*/
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext',
    function () {
        var textarea = document.getElementById('onetidIODefTextValue1'),
            status = function (text, color) {
                SP.UI.Status.removeAllStatus(true);
                SP.UI.Status.setStatusPriColor(SP.UI.Status.addStatus(text), color);
            };
        status('CalcMaster loaded', 'yellow');
        textarea.onkeyup = function (event) {
            if ([37, 38, 39, 40].indexOf(event.keyCode) < 0) { //ignore arrow keys
                clearTimeout(typing);
                var typing = setTimeout(function () {
                    var guid = _spPageContextInfo.pageListId.slice(1, 37),
                        title = document.getElementById('idColName').value,
                        formula = STSHtmlDecode(textarea.value),
                        ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
                        fields = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getById(guid).get_fields(),
                        field = ctx.castTo(fields.getByInternalNameOrTitle(title), SP.FieldCalculated);
                    //formula = ('=IF(TRUE,1,2)');
                    field.set_formula(formula);
                    field.update();
                    status('Saving: ' + title, 'blue');
                    ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {
                        status('Formula saved!', 'green');
                    }, function (sender, args) {
                        status(args.get_message(), 'red');
                    });
                }, 500); //debounce, do not save while typing
            }
        };
    }
);
```

### Additional info for 200-point Bounty hunters

You can extract the English formula using JSOM from the schemaXml

```
        var schemaXml=document.createElement('DIV');
        schemaXml.innerHTML=field.get_schemaXml();
        schemaXml=schemaXml.firstChild;
        var formula=schemaXml.getElementsByTagName('Formula')[0].innerText;
```

## BUT

- This formula returns the *Internal* (and english) names for Columnnames, so saving it causes an error because it does not match the Displaynames (eg. Taskname/Title)
- The , or ; separator also needs to be tackled

iJS

Comment: Without any code, can you save your formula using the dutch columns ? Because me, in french, I get the message saying the column doesn't exists. Looks like the formula needs to be created in the base language of the site.

Comment: Yes, JayHell, The OK button (normal SharePoint behaviour) works just fine. And yes, thomius, your link describes the same issue, yet without a solution.

Comment: There's also FormulaDisplayNames available (exposed at least via web services) but it didn't help solve the issue I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sadly a lot of things don't work as expected in CSOM. As a last resort I have a small hack - simply open the desired page as iframe, modify the content and submit the page. Quite slow but at least it works.

```
//quite dirty hack but at this point the only possibility to set the localized formula via clientside
function setFieldFormula(listGuid, fieldInternalName, newFormula, cb) {
    var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
    var url = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + '/_layouts/15/FldEdit.aspx?List=%7B' + listGuid+ '%7D&Field=' + fieldInternalName;
    //create hidden iframe
    iframe.setAttribute('src', url);
    iframe.setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
    iframe.onload = function () {
        //this will fire 2 times - the first time when its initially loaded. the second after the changes were applied (page is reloaded (postback) after the submitbutton is triggered)
        var formularInput = iframe.contentWindow.document.querySelector('.ms-formula');
        if (formularInput) {
            //initial load - apply settings
            formularInput.value  = newFormula;
            //trigger the post
            iframe.contentWindow.SubmitPage(false)
        } else {
            //second load - do callback
            cb && cb();
        }
    };
    document.body.appendChild(iframe);
}

setFieldFormula(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId.slice(1, 37), 'Berechnet', '=WAHR', function(){  //=WAHR is german for =TRUE and Berechnet is the title of my calculated column
    console.log('Done')
});
```

Due to the livesync in your code this is not applicable for your exact usecase but maybe you can replace the livesync with a triggered save (by a button for example).

If someone want's to discuss if this is a valid way of doing things - I've already asked a question for this:

[Manipulating SharePoint UI over an IFrame to add missing clientside Features](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/136377/manipulating-sharepoint-ui-over-an-iframe-to-add-missing-clientside-features)