# Set-SPOWeb -RequestAccessEmail

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, cmdlets

I found in [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87623/set-request-access-email-address-through-csom) that it is possible to `Set-SPOWeb` properties, in particular RequestEmailAddress. Obviously the guy did not dream it up and the number of upvotes suggests that it works for other users as well. Not for me.

1. I checked official documentation https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161364.aspx - the cmdlet is not there.
2. The cmdlet is available on some custom GitHub solutions, but not with that parameter, and the original post refers to SharePoint Online Management Shell.
3. There is SP-Web, but the original post clearly refers to ONLINE.
4. I reinstalled SharePoint Online Management Shell to make sure it is the latest version:
   [image]
5. The cmdlet is not TAB-able and when typed manually it gives a familiar error:
   [image]
6. I reproduced the same behaviour on 2 different computers in 2 different networks.

I really need the cmdlet, I saw it, I want it, and now I am frustrated. Please help.

Comment: Pretty sure that cmdlet does not exist. Try getting the web first and see if it has the propery on the `Web` object so you can set it that way

Comment: Thanks, Robert. There is no Get-SPOWeb cmdlet. To my understanding, SPO PS does not really work with objects below SPOSite level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no Set-SPOWeb. You can use the property by adding .dll as a reference to your project:
[image]

If you have the newest version, the property should become available:
[image]

Thank you all for helping me understand that better.