# Setting the request access Email through Javascript

Tags: 2013, javascript, permissions, email, requestaccessmail

I'm trying to set the Email adress where every access request are sent
Manually, this parameter is accessible through :  [Site Settings > Under Users and Permissions, Site Permissions > on the Permissions tab, Access Request Settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Set-up-and-manage-access-requests-94b26e0b-2822-49d4-929a-8455698654b3)

In CSOM, it's quite easy, [just set the `RequestAccessEmail` property of the `Web` instance](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/87623/set-request-access-email-address-through-csom)
But in Javascript, this property isn't accessible from SP.Web, it's nowhere to be seen : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb_properties.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

I've seen [a blog post](http://js231sharepoint.com/changing-the-access-requests-settings-of-a-sharepoint-online-site-with-javascript-jsom/) claming that it was possible using the function `this.web.set_requestAccessEmail();` wich turned out to not exist

Is there a way to do it ?

Comment: are you using sharepoint on premise ? Looks like it might be an issue with the CU version. If possible please try and upgrade to the latest CU. I have tried the code you mentioned in the blog link and it works in SharePoint online

Comment: Sharepoint on-premise is the one we use when we want to keep the website on our own server rather than the Microsoft cloud right ? If so, this is what we're using. I've never checked the CU version yet, I'll update my question after documenting myself ont that

Comment: yes that's on Premise :) . Although it might seem a long ask to update the server for such a small thing as this, would recommend that you upgrade your SP servers to the January/February 2018 CU for general improvements, bug fixes etc. Always a good idea to upgrade !

Comment: Alright thank you, And yeah, thats what I thought, updating the whole thing, even in preproduction might be an overkill for a single function. I'll link my superiors the details you agve me/what I found and let them decide, thank you